# How to avoid an OutOfMemoryException when using SetMaxThreads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to call a method many times (ten millon), therefore I use threads. But when the loop has 100 cycles of my method, it launchs an OutOfMemoryException.
I tried add SetMaxThreads to only run 50 threads simultaneous but don't works (because I don't know how to do it). Thanks in advance.

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 50);
for (int i = 0; i < tablePersons.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(RegisterPerson);
    t.Start(tablePersons.Rows[i]);
}

static void RegisterPerson(object paramObject)
{
   DataRow person = (DataRow)paramObject;
   Call a service...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating that many separate threads manually, you should probably use Parallel.ForEach(), and let that handle the thread creation for you.
They won't all run simultaneously, but you won't run into memory issues.

Answer (score 2):

1) You are confusing thread pool threads with user created threads.

This creates a new thread (not a thread pool thread):

```
Thread t = new Thread(RegisterPerson);
```

Seeting the Threadpool to have a maximum of fifty threads:

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 50);
```

has no effect on your loop, where you attempt to create a user thread for each row.

> There are a number of ways to enter the thread pool:
>
> - Via the Task Parallel Library (from Framework 4.0)
> - By calling ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
> - Via asynchronous delegates
> - Via BackgroundWorker

2) You should not be creating that many user threads.

I would suggest reading: Joe Albahari's excellent [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)